# 2008 Honda Civic EX Automatic (8th gen)-crank no start

Tags: honda, starting, civic, cranks-wont-run

My car is cranking but it doesn’t start. I didn’t drive it for a few days so I’m confused as to what could’ve gone bad because this is the first time it’s done it. No codes popping up. Battery is good, I tried another battery just to confirm. When I turn the key to (on II) I can hear the pump doing something so I don’t think is that. I checked the spark plugs but they are fine. What should I troubleshoot, and what order?

I gotta note that I installed an aftermarket radio and hardwired a dashcam about 3 weeks ago. That’s why my first thought was that the dashcam or radio drained the battery. Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is there a green key by chance showing on the dashboard?

Comment: Hey thank you. Yea, it flashes once then it goes away

Comment: You said you "checked the spark plugs" ... how did you go about verifying they are good? Did you check to see if there is spark when you crank it? Have you checked your fuses in cabin and underhood to ensure none are blown?

Comment: A bad crankshaft sensor can also do this. I would also check actual fuel pressure and confirm spark to spark plugs first.

Comment: Hey I’ve been too busy with the kids but today I finally checked the car some more (and been waiting for my tools from Amazon). I did the following by looking it up on YouTube: I got a new battery, checked all the fuses for continuity and with a test light and they seem to be fine, checked the spark plugs again using an inline spark tester and I’m getting a spark. I checked the fuel pressure by connecting the kit to the line behind the engine. It was 58psi which is perfect because Honda recommends 55-63. I then sprayed starting fluid into the air intake and the car started roughly for 2 secs.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is possible that the aftermarket radio messed up the CANBUS in the car somehow. Because your car is fairly recent ~2008, the CANBUS allows the car's immobilizer to communicate with the ECM. The backup camera could've messed up the CANBUS, as the CANBUS network is very susceptible to interference from other electrical system. Try rerouting the backup cam to another location, such as in the headliner instead. Hope this helped!

Comment: Ditto. I re-installed radio and it has been working fine. Camera was drawing power from reverse light and grounded to the reverse ground. I’m going to re-install the backup camera later and see how it affects anything.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following: I noticed that I hadn’t connected the cable that went to the antenna so connected it. I ended up disconnecting backup camera I recently installed. Then car just started (left it on ON for 90 seconds before cranking it). It ran a bit rough but other than that it didn’t stall and it started a few times afterwards! So, will be monitoring the next few days. What do you think could’ve happened?